# How to handle JWT expiration

Tags: jwt

I have a question on "make the browser send out a request to exchange for a new token at the sixth day. Accordingly, on the server side, create a restful API named /token/extend which will return a new token if given a valid token."

Let's assume that I implement this concept. When token is about to expire, we will generate new valid token if old valid token is provided.

Now, let's assume, Hacker gets the token. He uses this token to communicate with APIs. Hacker communicates for 6 days. On 6th day, our "/token/extend" API will generate new token for him so he can communicate for another 6 days, and probably forever. Will this situation occur? or Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The general way you would force your users to obtain a new token after 6 days would be by simply setting the `exp` field (expiry) in the claims of the JWT to expire after 6 days.  The exact mechanism by which users would use to obtain a new token depends on your implementation.

The most basic implementation would be to just let the incoming request on the sixth day to fail, forcing the consumer of the API to redirect to the login page.  From there, the user would have to login again to obtain a new valid JWT.  A more elaborate method would use refresh tokens.  With this approach, when the user first logs in, he would receive an authentication token with a 6 day expiry (as before), but would *also* receive a refresh token which would expire a little bit later.  On the sixth day, when the user tries to access a service, the request would again fail.  However, in this case, the consumer (e.g. a website or mobile app) could take the refresh token and request a new access token under the hood.  This would be a more seamless way of handling the mandatory 6 day expiry.  Note that with the refresh token approach, the user might never know about the 6 day expiry.

Regarding your concerns about hackers obtaining other people's tokens, you should mostly just forget about this.  If someone stole your wallet, there is all sort of havoc he could do to you, e.g. using your credit cards, stealing your identity, etc.  The same could happen with a stolen/sniffed JWT.  The best practice here is to just make sure you are using two-way SSL for all communication, and also encourage your users not to use your services in places like Internet cafes.